# Why is this swagger import failing?

Tags: postman

I am unable to import this swagger definition file with Postman 4.9.3. I can't get much debugging information out of Postman. Any ideas what's up?

http://docs.discourse.org/swagger.json

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you remove the line from /paths/uploads.json/post/parameters/in

```
"in": "formData",
```

then it imports fine.

Appears to be a bug in Postman and has been written up in [GitHub](https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/2687).

Try importing this (bad line removed)
https://paste.ee/r/TExNJ